# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable when converting a list to tuple as return value

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I want to convert the final list as tuple. However i am receiving an error.How can i get rid of this?

```
li= [(19343160,),(39343169,)]


def render_list_sql(li):
    l = []
    for index, tuple in enumerate(li):
        idd = str(tuple[0])
        l.append(idd)
    
    
    return tuple(l)
```

> `print(render_list_sql(li))`

```
Expected value to be returned is:
(19343160,39343169)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(render_list_sql(list))
  File "test.py", line 14, in render_list_sql
    return tuple(l)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: You are shadowing multiple names, please rename them. Also, you're using parenthesis on tuple. Why?

Comment: @12944qwerty I don't understand, would you please to clarify what should i change? i am new to python

Comment: `return tuple(l)` You're calling the tuple object. It isn't callable, hence the error. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with it though

Comment: You can't call your list 'list', that's a reserved keyword

Comment: Don't name your list `list`, don't name your tuple `tuple`, don't use `id`--they're reserved keywords. By naming variables with reserved keywords, you "shadow" them.

Comment: @chemicalwill changed, but i still have issue

Comment: @12944qwerty i have to get the result of that input as tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, don't use names for variables that mean other things to Python.  This is called "shadowing" and you lose the meaning of the original name.

Example:

```py
>>> tuple           # This is the class used to create tuples.
<class 'tuple'>
>>> for index,tuple in enumerate([1,2,3]):  # This is similar to your code
...     print(index,tuple)
...     
0 1
1 2
2 3
>>> tuple  # tuple is no longer a class, but an instance of an integer.
3
>>> tuple([1,2,3])  # so this fails
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> 3([1,2,3]) # You are basically doing this:
<interactive input>:1: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

So don't do that:

```py
li = [(19343160,),(39343169,)]  # don't reassign list

def render_list_sql(li):
    l = []
    for index, tup in enumerate(li):  # don't reassign tuple
        idd = str(tup[0])
        l.append(idd)
    return tuple(l)    # now this will work

print(render_list_sql(li))
```

Output:

```
('19343160', '39343169')
```

FYI, a shorter version using a generator:

```py
li = [(19343160,),(39343169,)]
tup = tuple(str(i[0]) for i in li)
print(tup)
```